# Variable inside an expression in python

Tags: python, variables

**EDIT: I am editing the whole question in order to be more clear, and to change something that was wrong in the previous example.**

Since I am really not sure how to explain the question, I will use the following example.

Let's say I have some classes that are called apple, banana and orange. I would like to create a function, that will take as an input one of these classes. Each class has a function that is called eating() that is what I want to call with the following function:

```
def function(banana):
    a = banana.eating()
    return a
```

The point is: if I put as an input the class apple, I would like a to take the value of `apple.eating()`. Hence, the name of the input variable should go in the expression somehow.

To be a bit more specific, the classes would be:

```
class apple:
    def __init__:
         blahblah
    def eating(self):
         blahblah

class banana:
     def __init__:
          blahblah
     def eating(self):
          blahblah
```

Comment: You *can* do something like this with `eval` but there is very likely a better solution if you provide more information (such as how those classes look like and how you defined those variables)

Comment: What's the problem with this:
`def func(name):
    fruit = name.function()
    return fruit`

Comment: You seem to have a perfectly good function `func()`, but what you don't show is firstly, how you create `banana` and `apple` and secondly how you call `func()`.

Comment: `globals()[name].function()` should work ... but its very very very very bad design.

Comment: The thing you’re asking for is already how it works, automatically, for any function call.  You can define an `apple` object outside the function and call `func(apple)` and the object `apple` will get the name `banana` (or `name` or whatever you call the parameter in your `def` statement) inside the function.

Comment: I see you have edited the question, but you still haven't shown how you create instances of `apple` and `banana`, nor how `function()` is called.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to do anything. Your code

```
def func(name):
    fruit = name.function()
    return fruit
```

will work al long as the argument you supply it is an object that has a `function` method.

Keep in mind that in Python "variables" are nothing more than *labels* that refer objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can inherit from a fruit metaclass

```
class fruit:
    def cfunc(self):
        print("Class: " + str(self.__class__))

class apple(fruit):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class banana(fruit):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

banana().func()
apple().func()

# Output:
# Class: <class '__main__.banana'>
# Class: <class '__main__.apple'>


def func(obj):
    return obj.cfunc()

func(banana())

# Output:
# Class: <class '__main__.banana'>
```